# midnight commander view mode: how to select all text

Tags: linux, mc

I am using midnight commander. To view the content of a .txt file I press F3. Then I can select text holding Shift + selecting with mouse:

[image]

But I would like to select the whole content of the file and it is not possible to scroll while I am selecting with the mouse.

Is there a "select all" option in that View mode?

Answer (score 1):

Midnight Commander cannot do it. You may want to file a feature request here: https://midnight-commander.org/wiki/NewTicket

Please use any graphical text editor instead.

On a second thought I don't believe it's technically possible. MC disables scrolling which means your terminal must and must not have a scrolling history at the same time. You cannot select `less` output which spans more than a single screen either.

Comment: Not quite: midnight commander uses the regular `smcup`/`rmcup` (*ti/te*) cursor-addressing mode, which generally switches to *alternate screen* (and **that** disables "scrolling").  But selecting a whole file would have to be done using new code in MC (unrelated to shifted-mouse selection), since the whole file is not on the terminal's screen/scrollback.